# Regarding the representation theory of $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, classical-groups

Dear friends of mathematics,
I have the following question for you.

(a) According to Wikipedia there is a unique irreducible (real??) $2$-dimensional representation of $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$, which must be the standard representation $i$ (for it is irreducible).

(b) If we take an automorphism $\phi$ of $SL_2$, then the representation $i\circ\phi$ must thus be isomorphic to $i$, which implies that $\phi$ is an inner automorphism. However, the group of outer automorphisms of $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$ is supposed to have order $2$, namely conjugation by the matrix $\mathrm{diag}(1,-1)$ should be an outer automorphism.

I think (a) and (b) contradict each other. How is this possible? Is the information given in Wikipedia wrong? Or does it refer to *complex* representations? For Wikipedia also says that the representation theory of $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$ is "the same" as the one of $SU_2$, in which case it would be true for *complex* representations.

If this is true, how many real $2$-dimensional irreducible representations does $SL_2$ have? References are much welcome. How is the general relationship between complex and real representations?
Also I wonder how the 2-dimensional real irreducible repreentations of $SL_2(R)$ are related to the 2-dimensionl complex irred reps of $SL_2(\mathbf{C})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that $i\circ\phi$ is isomorphic to $i$ doesn't imply that $\phi$ is an inner automorphism.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it is true that it implies that $\phi$ is of the form $\phi_R=R(-)R^{-1}$ right? Your point is that (unless $R$ has determinant $>0$) $R$ need not be (up to a scalar multiple) an element of $SL_2$. Over the complex numbers it would be an inner automorphism, though?

Comment: But is it true that $SL_2$ has only one $2$-dim irred rep?

Comment: In the above $R$ is a member of $GL_2$

Comment: I would like to accept your answer, but I would like to know whether I understand it correctly. I mean if $i\circ\phi$ is isomorphic to $i$ implies that there is $R\in GL_2$ such that for all $A\in SL_2$ we have $\phi(A)\circ R=R\circ A$.

Comment: @HerrHarryHeiner Yes, that's correct. And to answer the question in your previous comment, yes, $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$ has only one $2$-dimensional real irreducible representation: the classification of the finite-dimensional irreducible representations is the same whether you're looking at real or at complex representations.

Comment: ! Thanks for your fast response!